# how do i mock requests.get().url with side_effect?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have the following code:

```
def consuming_api_swapi_index_page(initial_page: int = 1):
    """Swapi index page."""
    check = HTTPStatus.OK
    results = []
    while check == HTTPStatus.OK:
        response = requests.get(
            f'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page={initial_page}'
        )
        results.append(url := response.url)
        print(url)
        check = response.status_code
        initial_page += 1
    return results


def test_consuming_api_swapi_index_page() -> None:
    """Test it."""
    values = [
        'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=1',
        'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2',
        'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=3',
        'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=4',
        'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=5',
        'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=6',
        'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=7',
        'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=8',
        'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=9',
        'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=10',
    ]

    assert consuming_api_swapi_index_page() == values
```

I need to mock it, How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matching.html you will be able to mock requests matching a regex, as

```
matcher = re.compile(r"https://swapi.dev/api/people/\?page=\d")
adapter.register_uri('GET', matcher, text='response')
```

### Edit

If you need different responses you can create a custom matcher: https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matching.html#custom-matching

Comment: the list not is a possibilities, they are answers for the test.